# Is it OK for me to track visits to my Stack Exchange profile, questions, & answers?

Tags: discussion, ethics, tracking

I would like to track visits to my Stack Overflow profile.

Is it acceptable to use a transparent GIF image (or other means) to get a request to my host and record visitors' IP address, time, user agent, etc.?

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from doing that, but why?

Comment: Long story, ... I am sending potential customers to my SO profile and would like to know if they did visit it and when.

Comment: Sounds sketchy as hell. Now, a big picture of your grinning face, with the caption, "I IZ TRACKIN U"...

Comment: Yes, if you're sneaky and use a non-transparent image so nobody assumes you're tracking them.

Comment: This question is referred to from this more recent question: [Is it appropriate to add third-party tracking scripts or web bugs to individual questions, answers, and profile pages?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231608/is-it-appropriate-to-add-third-party-tracking-scripts-or-web-bugs-to-individual)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How would that work, exactly?

Sure, you can upload an image to your profile, but Stack Exchange makes a copy of it and puts it on imgur, so it doesn't make a request to *your* server (although embedding `<img>` tags does work).

In any case, even if you could, it would probably violate Section 3(e) of the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), which prohibits uploading anything that surreptitiously collects information.

Comment: He's saying he'd put it in his bio I think.

Comment: You know, [like this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5933/1324). Only more sinister and term-violatey.

Comment: You can still link directly to external images, can't you?

Comment: Also re 3(e) - meh. I don't see that clause prohibiting web bugs. Any normally configured web server will record access information for external images. What's the difference? If I were @Majid, I'd just do it.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Sure, but the user would have to click on the link directly.  And no, *that's* not prohibited, because it's clearly apparent to the user that clicking on the link will take him somewhere else.

Comment: @Robert no, I mean we can embed external images. That's how minitech's browser game thingy above works, doesn't it?

Comment: @Pekka웃: In that case, I say put up a *visible* image at your discretion.  I see no need to hide it a la web beacon, however; that's just sleazy, and it *does* violate the TOS.  See Shog9's comment below the question.

Comment: Ultimately, I don't think there is a huge difference between using some random image, and a transparent one. The data is collected in both cases, and there is nothing the user can do about it.  A transparent image will make you *look* sleazy though.

Comment: @Pekka웃: The difference is that the transparent image deliberately hides the data collection from the user, whereas the non-transparent image does not.  It's a non-trivial difference.  Granted, you need specialized knowledge to understand the difference anyway, but a hidden GIF would require viewing the page source to identify, which most users should not be reasonably expected to do.

Comment: @Robert does the latter apply, though? When you see an image in a user profile, do you think "oh, that must be there to collect my data"? My point is, if we don't want sleazy people collecting data, we need to prohibit images from external sources. I don't see the point in telling the one decent guy who actually *asks* (and likely has no evil motives) that he can't do it, while anyone can just do it with no means for us to find out.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Frankly, I'm a bit surprised that we routinely anonymize image uploads, but still allow bare links to images.  It must be to minimize hotlinking.  Still, I don't think its too much to ask to make it clear in your profile that you *might* be collecting usage data from a clearly visible GIF, rather than hiding behind a transparent one.  It's just the right thing to do.  If you're trying to hide what you're doing, you probably shouldn't be doing it in the first place.

Comment: With a transparent pixel, that’s obviously information collection and not allowed. With some other image, it could be information collection and not allowed, but there’s really no way to be sure except disallowing external images (which is really no fun at all), so…

Comment: @RobertHarvey, going for a transparent GIF, the intention was not to hide anything, it just would free you from worrying about aesthetics of the outcome with a visible one.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: Your good intentions don't change the web beacon's hinky nature.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I had a [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231608/218097) that was marked as a duplicate of this one, so just to clarify, users are not allowed to post tracking images like this in their questions and answers either, right?

Comment: @JohnBensin: I find the terms of service link to be conclusive enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree (and I agree that with Chris' most recent edit to this question, my question is a duplicate of this one)

Comment: @JohnBensin: I've commented on the post, and removed all beacons I could find.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks; I presume the tracking beacons will be removed from the profile pages as well?

Comment: @JohnBensin: I'll flag a post per site where this user is using the technique.

Comment: @MartijnPieters have you found *this user* to ever having used *this technique* even once? Your comment implies I have; a baseless and wrong accusation.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: please read the comment thread carefully, you missed the context. I was discussing the [other post duplicated here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231608).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, my apologies, but it was too easy to miss the context. There is a clarification from you now, which is good.