# Is it appropriate to add third-party tracking scripts or web bugs to individual questions, answers, and profile pages?

Tags: discussion, privacy

On several sites (SO, Money), a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555155/cmpsoares) has added third-party [tracking beacons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371157/2001600) to questions, answers, and his profile pages. Is this appropriate, or should these tracking beacons be removed from posts?

In my opinion, this behavior should be **strongly** discouraged because it raises potentially thorny issues of consent. By using the SE family of sites, I agree to their terms of service (and the terms of service of any third-party providers that they use) that govern how they use any information they collect from me. However, I have no such agreement with every user on every SE site and/or every third-party tracking tool out there, which means that any information collected from me through these sources is essentially ungoverned and done without my implicit/explicit agreement.

---

To be clear, this question is similar to the linked question, but I think it's worthwhile to clarify that this behavior is disallowed *everywhere*, not just in user profile pages.

Comment: Hrm, I am not sure I'm comfortable with such behaviour, no.

Comment: Note that that self-answered post is better off being moved to Meta.SO.

Comment: Showing the technique as he did in SO seems ok, but injecting actual beacons as was [done in Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/posts/30460/revisions) doesn't look good, at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, as I understand it, he used stackoverflow.com as an example, but the concept is to be used in any site where you have publishing capabilities (eg, GitHub). He [cross-posted](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14354/como-faco-para-adicionar-analise-em-tempo-real-das-visualizacoes-nas-minhas-perg/14355#14355) the same at [pt.so].

Comment: @brasofilo: the linked question **does** contain the beacon. I am having some trouble constructing a search that shows all posts with the beacon, looks like I have to use a SEDE query instead. But the beacon *is being used*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but will the beacon work marked down as `code`?

Comment: @brasofilo: No, but the question post contains the `![beacon][1]` image.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, fluck, I was checking only the Answer, the beacon is in the Question... Shall we edit or wait for your SEDE to catch all?

Comment: @brasofilo: SEDE is currently timing out, but it's nothing more than a `SELECT Id AS [Post Link] FROM Posts WHERE Body LIKE '%https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/UA-%';` query.

Comment: SEDE query: http://data.stackexchange.com/money/query/194194/search-for-ga-beacon-appspot-com-1-pixel-tracking-images. Works on Money (finds the two posts John neutered), times out on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Note that the beacon is also present on his profile pages, which I doubt the SEDE will pick up (although it's trivial to check manually).

Comment: When I limit the query to just the original user's posts, I find [Setup bash script for aws ubuntu server node.js installation fails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23189968), [Multiple Analytics Providers on Jekyll Bootstrap Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23582321), [Appending multiple returned values to different lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23400799), [ASP.NET Service.exe isn't picked up by GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23244933) and [Difference between MEAN.js and MEAN.io](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23199392)

Comment: SEDE query limited to posts created in the past year: same posts, just this user is using them on Stack Overflow.

Comment: While it is trivial to insert a tracker that no one can recognize in the form of an external image resource, this is never appropriate and any overt occurrences of something like this should be removed.

Comment: A more drastic way to deal with this issue would be to disallow embedded images from any sources other than the official SE imgur account. Using other image hosts is already heavily discouraged as they are much more likely to expire at some point.

Comment: Closed as duplicate? Really? I'd suggest this issue is broader than tracking visits to one's profile page. Perhaps that *other* Q&A should be updated to be a canonical answer about the general practice.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea closed as **no, this violates TOS**, just flag it. The *method* of input, however, may be another question all together as it may be a *bug*.

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm referring to the closure of *this* meta question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea exactly. This is a duplicate of the other as the other specifically states that this is a violation of the TOS. No need for additional conversation about it.

Comment: Hi guys, it seems I'm the one targeted with this question, I can give a small and simple explanation for  what happened. I used it as first as a way to show the technique as brasofilo suggested but I concluded with that little experience that it can get certain conclusions that help improve question quality and with that reputation. I use it sometimes with other uses and until now hadn't have a problem so I injected it into every question and answer of mine. What I think I did wrong was being naive to the point of thinking that an innocent beacon wouldn't harm anyone. I apologize for that.